# Knockout multiselect dropdown with lazy loading

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am having difficulties with this handler I have partially gotten from here and partially hacked together. I am still getting my bearings on the handlers so I am assuming my issues is stemming from a lack of understanding.

I am using this handler in a template that is displayed inside a ko "if" statement. When the template is being included/excluded on and off options are duplicating. This is because of the `unwrap(valueAccessor()).push(item)` line. I have tried just building the array independantly and then setting the valueAccessors value to the array directly but the ui does not respond, it only works by pushing the items.

How can I get around this? Am I doing the binding correctly or is there a better more appropriate way? I have marked the line of code with a comment to indicate where my problem is happening.

```
multiSelectCheck: {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
            // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
            var bindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var ddOptions = unwrap(valueAccessor);
            var selectedOptions = unwrap(bindings.selectedOptions);
            var options = unwrap(bindings.multiselectOptions) || [];
            var optionsCaption = unwrap(bindings.optionsCaption);
            var displaySelected = unwrap(bindings.selectedList) || 5;
            var loadingCaption = unwrap(bindings.loadingCaption);
            var delimiter = unwrap(bindings.splitSelectedBy) || ',';
            var setInitial = unwrap(bindings.setInitialValue);

            // display loader in dropdown
            ko.computed(function () {
                if (unwrap(bindings.loading)) {
                    var spinnerClass = 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg';
                    var spinner = loadingCaption || '<span><i class="' + spinnerClass + '"></i> Loading...</span>';

                    // set text to loading
                    $(element).multiselect({ selectedList: 0, noneSelectedText: spinner, selectedText: spinner }).multiselect('disable');
                    $(element).multiselect('refresh');
                }
            }, null, { disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element });

            // internal options
            var internal = { selectedList: displaySelected, noneSelectedText: 'Select options', selectedText: '# selected' }

            // merge options with provided options
            options = $.extend(internal, options);

            // pass the original optionsCaption to the similar widget option
            if (optionsCaption) {
                options.noneSelectedText = unwrap(optionsCaption);
            }

            // remove this and use the widget's
            bindings.optionsCaption = '';

            // populate intitial values if available
            if (ddOptions && !ddOptions.length && setInitial) {

                if (selectedOptions) {

                    // create array from value
                    if (typeof selectedOptions == 'string') {
                        selectedOptions = selectedOptions.split(delimiter);
                        selectedOptions = selectedOptions.filter(function (e) { return !!e; }); // filter empty nodes
                        bindings.selectedOptions(selectedOptions);
                    }

                    // add options objects to array of available options
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectedOptions.length; i++) {
                        var item = { Value: selectedOptions[i], Text: '' };
                        //console.log(item);

                        //#### THIS IS THE LINE OF CODE IN QUESTION ####
                        unwrap(valueAccessor()).push(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            // apply multiselect plugin
            var elm = $(element).multiselect(options).multiselectfilter({ filterOnly: true, autoReset: true });

            // refresh the plugin
            $(element).multiselect('refresh');

            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                elm.multiselectfilter('destroy').multiselect("destroy");
                $(element).remove();
            });

        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
            // and again whenever the associated observable changes value.
            // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
            var bindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var selectOptions = unwrap(bindings.multiSelectCheck);
            var selectedOptions = unwrap(bindings.selectedOptions);
            var delimiter = unwrap(bindings.splitSelectedBy) || ',';
            var displaySelected = unwrap(bindings.selectedList) || 5;

            // remove this and use the widget's 
            bindings.optionsCaption = '';

            // handle delimited values
            if (typeof selectedOptions == 'string') {
                selectedOptions = selectedOptions.split(delimiter);
                selectedOptions = selectedOptions.filter(function (e) { return !!e; }); // filter empty nodes
                bindings.selectedOptions(selectedOptions);
            }

            ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
            var data = unwrap(valueAccessor());
            var showFilter = (data && data.length > 10) ? 'enable' : 'disable';

            setTimeout(function () {
                var $element = $(element);
                $element.multiselect({ selectedList: displaySelected, noneSelectedText: 'Select options', selectedText: '# selected' }).multiselect('enable').multiselect('refresh').multiselectfilter('refresh');
                $element.multiselectfilter(showFilter);
                $element.multiselect('refresh');
            }, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So my problem ended up being that I thought I had the array value, but I ended up having the observable instead. This caused my array length check to always pass so it kept adding the initial values.

I had to change the init line

```
var ddOptions = unwrap(valueAccessor);
```

To

```
var ddOptions = unwrap(valueAccessor()); // added () :/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create temporary array with items and update valueAccessor observable array directly:

```
var items = [];
for (var i = 0; i < selectedOptions.length; i++) {
   items.push({ Value: selectedOptions[i], Text: '' });
}

// items
valueAccessor(items);
```

Comment: I have tried this as well but the values do not update then. I have also tried setting the valueAccessor to a blank array and then adding the initial values but that hasn't worked either. :/